# @DataJpaTest analogue for Spring Data neo4j testing

Tags: spring, testing, neo4j, spring-data, spring-boot-test

Is it an analog of @DataJpaTest or @MockMvc annotation that can be used in combination with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) for a typical DAO test. 
Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to neo4j repository tests.

Answer (score 2):

You can use @DataNeo4jTest instead of @DataJpaTest.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-neo4j-test

Comment: Was added into Spring Boot 2.0.0. Thanks!